# How to correctly pass a function with parameters to another function?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, callback, c++17

I have the following code to demonstrate a function been called inside another function.

The below code works correctly:

```
#include <iostream>

int thirds()
{
    return 6 + 1;
}
template <typename T, typename B>
int hello(T x, B y , int (*ptr)() ){
    
    int first = x + 1;
    int second = y + 1;
    int third = (*ptr) (); ;
    
    return first + second + third;
}
int add(){
    
     int (*ptr)() = &thirds;
    return hello(1,1, thirds);
}
int main()
{
    std::cout<<add();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to pass one number as a parameter from add function ie into thirds function (thirds(6)).

I am trying this way:

```
#include <iostream>

int thirds(int a){
    return a + 1;
}

template <typename T, typename B>
int hello(T x, B y , int (*ptr)(int a)() ){
    
    int first = x + 1;
    int second = y + 1;
    int third = (*ptr)(a) (); ;
    
    return first + second + third;
}

int add(){
    
     int (*ptr)() = &thirds;
    return hello(1,1, thirds(6)); //from here pass a number
}

int main()
{
    
    std::cout<<add();

    return 0;
}
```

My expected output is:

```
11
```

But It is not working. Please can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This might help you : [introduction to lambda functions](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-lambdas-anonymous-functions/), pay attention to captures.

Comment: Minor point: you don't need to write `(*ptr)()` to call the function; `ptr()` works just fine. Pointers to functions get dereferenced automatically. And, just for fun, you can write redundant dereferences: `(*****ptr)()` also calls the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you want `add` to pass a value to `hello`, to be passed to the function given by the pointer `ptr`, you have to add a separate parameter.
2. In c++ it is usually advised to use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of old c style funtion pointers.

**A complete example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int thirds(int a) 
{
    return a + 1;
}

template <typename T, typename B>
//------------------------------------------------VVVVV-
int hello(T x, B y, std::function<int(int)> func, int a) 
{
    int first = x + 1;
    int second = y + 1;
    int third = func(a);
    return first + second + third;
}

int add() 
{
    std::function<int(int)> myfunc = thirds;
    return hello(1, 1, myfunc, 6);
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << add();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
11
```

**Note:** another solution could be to use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to create a callable from `thirds` and the argument `6`. But I think the solution above is more simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

```
thirds(6)
```

yields a prvalue of type `int`. This cannot be converted to a function pointer. You need to pass `6` as separate parameter.

Note: The beauty of C++ here is that you don't actually need to know, what you're passing, as long as you're willing to use a parameter of a type specified as a template parameter. You don't even need to restrict the number of parameters the function can be used with. And you don't even need to bother with the function pointer syntax...

```
int thirds(int a) {
    return a + 1;
}

long f(std::string const& x, int y)
{
    return x.size() + y;
}

template <typename T, typename B, class Function, class ... Args>
auto hello(T x, B y, Function f, Args...args) // deduce the return type
{

    int first = x + 1;
    int second = y + 1;
    int third = f(args...);

    return first + second + third;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout
        << hello(1, 2, thirds, 6) << '\n'
        << hello(1, 2, f, "hello world", 8) << '\n'
        << hello(1, 2, []() {return 3; }) << '\n'
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

Btw: In practice you should probably use perfect forwarding, but I left this out in the code above make it a bit more beginner friendly.

Here's the version of the function I'd implement in practice:

```
template <typename T, typename B, class Function, class ... Args>
decltype(auto) hello(T&& x, B&& y, Function&& f, Args&&...args)
{
    return (std::forward<T>(x) + 1)
        + (std::forward<B>(y) + 1)
        + std::forward<Function>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does not seem to compile.
Have you tried something like the following?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int thirds(int a){
    return a + 1;
}

template <typename T, typename B>
int hello(T x, B y , int (*ptr)(int)){

    int first = x + 1;
    int second = y + 1;
    int third = ptr(first);

    return first + second + third;
}

int add(){

  int (*ptr)(int) = &thirds;
  return hello(1, 1, ptr); //from here pass a number
}

int main()
{

    std::cout << add();

    return 0;
}
```

In addition, I would suggest looking into [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).